# How to get path to library installed through elpa

Tags: package-repositories, path, load

I have Emacs installed on multiple machines, and every time I install yasnippet through elpa. As it's version changes, it is being installed into different directories. For example:

```
#first machine
~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20170518.1753
#second machine
~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20170828.1908
```

In `~/.emacs` I have the following code:

```
(defvar *my-emacs-lib-dir* "d:/bin/cygwin/home/user/.emacs.d/")
(defvar *yasnippet-dir* "~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20170518.1753")
(load-file (concat *my-emacs-lib-dir* "bootstrap-init.el"))
```

in `bootstrap-init.el` I load yasnippet library:

```
(load (concat *yasnippet-dir* "/yasnippet"))
(yas/global-mode 1)
```

Is it possible to get path to installed yasnippet library from elpa database? So I won't need to modify `*yasnippet-dir*` on every machine?

Comment: `(file-name-directory (locate-library "yasnippet"))`

Comment: @bertfred How to accept if it works?

Comment: You should be able to do `(load "yasnippet")`, or `(require 'yasnippet)` as long as you call `package-initialize` first. Actually even just `(yas-global-mode 1)` without loading should work since it's autoloaded.